# Что значит двойной амперсанд (&&) в параметрах функции и как его использовать?

Tags: c++, c++11

Перехожу в одиннадцатый стандарт из старого и в нем много нового для меня, в частности не понятно для чего в параметрах функций пишут двойной амперсанд **&&**. Неясно для чего он нужен и как его можно использовать?

Вот небольшой примерчик:

```
void test(int && a){
    a++;
    // как работать с таким параметром (а) внутри функции, например вывести ее на экран?
}

int main(){
    int a = 1;

    test(a); // как передать переменную?

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это rvalue reference. Очень большая тема.

Comment: Вот [вводная статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/226229/) о них.

Comment: спасибо @VladD думал это элементарные знания. ушел читать

Comment: Там в начале статьи написано: «Rvalue ссылки – маленькое техническое расширение языка C++.» Это не вполне правда, расширение далеко не маленькое.

Comment: @VladD, в 98 (помню точно, потому что тогда купил bc в ленкниге) встретился с исходником о пяти (`*****`) указателях. Понятие "ссылка" пришло позже :)

Comment: @PinkTux: Пять? Да ещё и в учебной книге? О боже.

Comment: @VladD, именно. Это было в примерах к BC 3.0 :) В деталях могу наврать, но что 5 - точно помню.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Пока читаете, для себя такое небольшое правило выработал:

1. `type&` - аргумент обязательно lvalue, т.е. то, что стоит слева от знака равно:

   ```
   int a = 1;
   foo(a); // a может быть изменено в foo и по выходу иметь другое значение
   foo(1); // ошибка компиляции
   ```
2. `const type&` - аргумент может быть как lvalue (при этом даёте гарантию, что он там не поменяется) или rvalue, тогда его время жизни продлевается на время вызова:

   ```
   int a = 1;
   bar(a); // а не меняется внутри
   bar(2); // тоже легально
   ```
3. `type&&` - аргумент может быть только rvalue, при этом внутри вызова можно его изменять и вообще, работаете как с обычной переменной (как только rvalue внутри функции обретает имя, оно "автоматом" становится lvalue :-)). Чтобы обычную переменную превратить в rvalue, нужно её "переместить", т.е. по сути, отдать владение в вызываемую функцию:

   ```
   int a = 1;
   baz(a); // ошибка компиляции
   baz(std::move(a)); // всё отлично, но после вызова состояние a не определено.
   baz(2); // тоже отлично, 2 - rvalue
   ```
4. `const type&&` - такая конструкция возможна, но её смысл для меня ускальзывает. Она сродни такому:

   ```
   void some(const int arg);
   ```

   т.е. просто внутри менять запрещаете.

Из правил вытекает использование: когда нужно отдать владение объектом. Возможна просто дополнительная перегрузка, чтобы можно было работать в одинаковом стиле в вызывающем коде как с rvalue, так и lvalue:

```
void foo(int& a);  // [1]
void foo(int&& a); // [2]
...
int a = 1;
foo(a); // вызовется [1]
foo(1); // вызовется [2]
foo(move(a)); // вызовется [2], состояние 'a' будет неопределено.
```

Answer (score 7):

Чтобы было понятнее, что именно делает `&&`, сравним три «классических» способа передачи аргумента (раз в вопросе фигурирует именно это применение «амперсандов»):

1. Передача **по левосторонней ссылке** (`Type&`). Это самый простой случай; копируется только указатель на объект (чем ссылка и является на самом низком уровне).
2. Передача **по значению** (`Type`). В этом случае компилятор создаёт полноценную копию объекта путём выделения памяти на стеке и вызова *конструктора копирования*.
3. И наконец, передача **по правосторонней ссылке** (`Type&&`). Здесь компилятор также выделяет место на стеке, однако вызывает уже *конструктор перемещения*, задача которого — «переместить» все данные из исходного объекта в новый, превратив первый в «пустышку» (безопасную с точки зрения отсутствия связи с данными нового объекта).

   Почему «переместить» было написано в кавычках? Да потому, что по факту выполняется простое копирование с занулением оригинала.

Следом может возникнуть вопрос: если всё сводится к простому копированию с обнулением, почему нельзя обойтись старой доброй *передачей по значению*? Ведь можно предположить, что простого отбрасывания данных оригинала при его уничтожении вполне достаточно. Дело в том, что это верно не всегда. Класс может содержать указатели (как, к примеру, `std::vector`) или дескрипторы внешних ресурсов (как `std::fstream`). Если выполнить просто *копирование* экземпляров этих классов, то мы получим:

- либо «глубокое» копирование всего буфера у `std::vector`,
- либо две ссылки на один и тот же файловый дескриптор у `std::fstream`; уничтожение одного экземпляра класса приведёт к появлению некорректного дескриптора у другого.