# Как поставить такой символ?

Tags: android-studio

[image: Подскажите пожалуйста, что за символ используется в коде]

Подскажите мне, что за знаки используются в написании данного кода. Я не очень понимаю как поставить данный символ. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Это амперсанд & поставленный дважды. Со стандартной клавиатурой ставится как Shift + 7  в англоязычной раскладке

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что значит двойной амперсанд (&&) в параметрах функции и как его использовать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512284/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 5):

& - это так называемый "Амперса́нд". Два таких знака образуют в языке программирования Java Логический оператор "И" (AND)

Поставить его можно с помощью клавиатуры Shift + 7(не в панели Num Lock'а)

Если у вас по какой-то причине не выводиться данный символ, это возможно ошибка IDE. Либо проблема клавиатуры. Если проблема в клавиатуре вы можете воспользоваться виртуальной клавиатурой. "Экранная клавиатура" в спец возможностях ОС Windows.