# Что означает && возле типа и когда использовать?

Tags: c++

Я знаю, что есть указатели * и ссылки &. Первое для адресов, чтобы не копировать значения лишний раз, а второе то же самое, но без явного разыменования и взятия адреса. Но что такое двойная ссылка &&? Когда её надо использовать для объявления моих переменных?

Comment: Если две секунды поискать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512284/

Comment: @MBo это да! но мне надо в переменных а не в функциях

Comment: Покажите пример, а то, может, у вас вообще логическое И...

Comment: @MBo auto&& price = contract.get_price() вот строчка например

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us

Comment: 1) В Си ссылок нет. 2) Данную семантику имеют как `rvalue reference` так и `forward reference`.

Comment: @megorit Имели в виду синтаксис, не семантику?

Answer (score 2):

`T && x = ..` - это объявление ссылки на объект, у которого заканчивается время жизни или он вообще временный объект.

```c++
int f ( int x ) {
  return x + 1 ;
}

int && r = f ( 1 ) ;
```

Это объявление можно использовать для оптимизации, чтобы не было и мысли для создания копии возвращаемого объекта. И ссылка `r` будет ссылаться на временный возвращаемый объект функцией `f`. Этому временному объекту будет увеличена время жизни до конца видимости переменной `r`.

---

Нельзя создавать переменную данной ссылкой, если функция возвращает не объект, а `&&` ссылку. Так как после завершения выполнения функции у этих временных объектов может заканчиваться срок жизни. И ваша новая ссылка будет уже неликвидная.

```c++
int && g ( int && x ) {
  return static_cast<int&&>(x) ;
}

int && r = g ( 1 ) ; // так нельзя
```

У временного объекта 1 заканчивается время жизни после завершения выполнения функции `g` и ссылка `r` будет уже указывать на удалённый временный объект.
В таких случаях нужно возвращать копию объекта, а не ссылку.

```c++
int g ( int && x ) {
  return static_cast < int && > ( x ) ;
}

int && r = g ( 1 ) ; // можно
```

*Из-за непредсказуемого поведения времени жизни возвращаемого временного объекта, лучше всегда из функции возвращать только копию.*

Answer (score 0):

Это rvalue ссылка. В объявлении переменных надо использовать, когда то, чем инициализируете является rvalue ссылкой и при этом у вас нет move конструктора.

```cpp
NonMovable&& a = get_rvalue_reference_to_NonMovable()
```

`auto&&` это forwarding ссылка. В объявлении переменных надо использовать, когда интересна константность или категория выражения, возвращаемая инициализатором. Обычно это надо в обобщённом коде для идеальной передачи возвращаемого значения. Например, в итерировании по вектору неизвестного типа можно использовать, чтобы работало и для вектора bool.